# Angular 7 email validation using regex on reactive form

Tags: angular, regex, forms, validation

On Angular, I am trying to validate email using following regex -

```
^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

Like below -

```
createGroupForm() {
    this.childGroupForm = new FormGroup({
        'groupName': new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([
            Validators.required
        ])),
        'groupEmail': new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([
            Validators.pattern('^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$')
        ]))
    });
}
```

But looks like it's not working. It always display "Email is invalid.", even though it is valid.

Comment: can you show the template ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I made an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgc7st

So in the Validator it should be like this:

```
Validators.pattern(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)
```

If you see in you code you are entering an string as reexp. so removing the string char ('') it works. Check the example.

Answer (score 1):

Regex in `javascript` should not be passed as a `string` but should have `/` at start and end like:

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

so try this:

```
createGroupForm() {
    this.childGroupForm = new FormGroup({
        'groupName': new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([
            Validators.required
        ])),
        'groupEmail': new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([
            Validators.pattern(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)
        ]))
    });
}
```

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regx. I hope it will works for you.

```
emailregx: /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
```

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It run well.

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```